# How to set System Photo Library using the command line?

Tags: photos.app, macos

I know that I can set the System Photo library in Photos.app in Preferences > Use as System Photo Library

I would like to know how to set this using the command line, giving the new System Photo Library location as a parameter.

The background for this is that I keep my Photos library in Dropbox, and I have found that if I have it set to the System Photo Library on more than one Mac, I get file conflicts due to background processing - so I would like to do some scripting to work around some of these issues.